# Inverse Fourier Transform with magnitude only - do I need the phase as well?

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning, fft

I used the Short Time Fourier Transform on a random wav file and performed some changes on the magnitude spectrum. To "hear" what I did, I'm trying to reverse the process by using the inverse STFT.

In Python the spectrum looks like this.
[Magnitude Spectrum in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu6V6.png)

However, if I'm trying to convert the whole thing back into a wav and look at its spectrum it looks like this:
[Magnitude Spectrum after ISTFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haxkr.png)

I'm just using the magnitude for the Inverse FFT. What am I doing wrong? **Do I need the phase signal as well? And can I use the same phase signal even if I manipulated the magnitude?**

```
# ....read wav-file, perform STFT on it and manipulate the magnitude spectrum
# Then (as follows) I'm trying to write it back
fs = 41000.0 # Frequency Spectrum

filteredwrite = istft(magnitude)

from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write
write('../data/mxx.wav', fs, filteredwrite.astype(x.dtype))
```

The Fourier functions work properly if I'm doing ifft(fft(F)) - nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

The phase is required to reconstruct the original signal because the relative phases of the component frequencies determine the superposition of those waves.

Comment: Now I added the initial phase and the signal looks completely the same and messed up...